# Javascript copy and pasting doesn't format model value correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, javascript-objects, dom-events

I am making an SSN formatter. Here is my code:

```
            element.keyup(function(event) {
                var inputField = event.target;
                var val = inputField.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                var newVal = '';
                if(val.length > 3 && val.length < 6) {
                    newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
                    val = val.substr(3);
                }
                if (val.length > 5) {
                    newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
                    newVal += val.substr(3, 2) + '-';
                    val = val.substr(5,4);
                }
                newVal += val;
                inputField.value = newVal;
            })
            .keypress(function(event) {
                if(event.target.value.length === 11) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                }
             });
```

Entering numbers manually works fine however,
When I copy and paste a number such as 12345678901234567890
the text box will format it to 123-45-6789 however the model value still says it is 12345678901234567890, if I backspace delete one number from 123-45-6789 then the model value will become 123-45-678

I am not sure what is going on? Is it because of keyup event? Not sure. would appreciate help.

Comment: Could you provide a running code example to test your issue?

Comment: What do you mean running code example?

Comment: A working example here http://jsbin.com/ or directly on SO (Edit your Question, press CTRL+M).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's because of the keyup event, which doesn't detect your paste. You should use the input event instead:

```
        element.on("input", function(event) {
            var inputField = event.target;
            var val = inputField.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            var newVal = '';
            if(val.length > 3 && val.length < 6) {
                newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
                val = val.substr(3);
            }
            if (val.length > 5) {
                newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
                newVal += val.substr(3, 2) + '-';
                val = val.substr(5,4);
            }
            newVal += val;
            inputField.value = newVal;
        })
        .keypress(function(event) {
            if(event.target.value.length === 11) {
              event.preventDefault();
            }
         });
```